# Shelf Life of Super Capacitor

Tags: supercapacitor, lifetime

Why shelf life (storage of caps in non-operational condition at constant temperature) of super capacitor is less as compared to operational life? How to determine the shelf life of supercapacitor at various temperature?

Comment: Last I checked a discharged supercapacitor had essentially unlimited shelf life. Where are you getting this information from?

Comment: Hi Matt, I checked datasheet of various vendors like DCN (shelf life of 500 hrs @ 60 degree celsius), bestcap (1000 hrs @ 70 degree celsius) etc. I am not able to understand why stated shelf life in datasheet is much less than operating life of super cap (calculated by Arrhenius equation at operational voltage and temp value)

Comment: Something is very strange about those specs.  500 Hours is only about 20 days. Do you have a link to the datasheet(s)?

Comment: Hi Tcrosley,                                                       Please find the below links for datasheets:                     http://www.illinoiscapacitor.com/pdf/DCN.pdf                     http://www.avx.com/docs/catalogs/bestcap.pdf                   You can search self life in both of them for more info.         Thanks

Comment: I agree, those numbers are nuts. They must be using those terms (Lifetime and Shelf Life) to mean something else, possible related to the number of cycles (500,000). That would sorta make sense.  Also, up above, they've got a smaller table of Surge voltage with three columns, and no titles for the columns.

Comment: As far as I know shelf life is for non operational condition where as lifetime is for operational condition. We can use Arrhenius equation to calculate lifetime for supercap. But I was wonder on what basis they are throwing numbers for shelf life!

Answer (score 1):

So I looked up what you were talking about. Under normal circumstances, you should be fine, so long as you're using the cap around room temp, and with a reasonable air/water mix. Here's what one of the spec sheets says:

> AVX BestCap®
>
> supercapacitor ***is unaffected by the following***
> storage conditions:
> Temperature: 15°C ~ 35°C
> Humidity: 45% RH ~ 75% RH
>
> This temperature and humidity range is specified for ***consideration of terminal solderability***. BestCap® are able to withstand shelf life ***at 70ºC for 1000 hours.***

So basically, you should be fine so long as you're not cooking the thing at 70C or 158F for 1000 hours.

Comment: Hi Lesley, That's true but I still want to know about the short shelf life period. Is it just because of terminal solder issue or it has to do something with super capacitor degradation?

Comment: The first sentence pretty much tells you that the super cap has an indefinite shelf-life so long as you keep it within the defined storage parameters.

Later on in the PDF it lists a bunch of tests they performed on the product, but they don't really exceed 70C in any of them. If you look at Capacitance vs. Temperature graph in the spec sheet they stop even testing at 60C.

Comment: It's because all those test cases are for operational condition of supercap. Shelf life is non operatinal condition where cap is kept at particular temp for a certain period and tested for its capacitance/ESR degradation.

Comment: My read on the 1000hrs is that this is how long they guarantee before the terminals oxidize and inhibit soldering. Nothing to do with the operation once in circuit.

Comment: It could be, BenG. I personally own a few ultracaps myself and they've been good for well over 2 years now.

Answer (score 0):

The ability of capacitors to have a stable behavior during longer storage times can be tested by using an accelerating test of storing the capacitors at its upper category temperature for a certain period, usually 1000 hours without voltage applied. This "shelf life test" is a good indicator for an inert chemically behavior because all chemical reactions are accelerated by high temperatures. Nearly all today's series of capacitors fulfill the 1000 hours shelf life test, which is equivalent to **a minimum five years of storage at room temperature**.